# Inline css in html.html.twig | Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I would like to insert a style tag with inline CSS to the file html.html.twig
I'm running Drupal 8 with Bartik theme.
I want it to look something like this in the front end.

```
<style media="all">
  html{background:#fff;color:#000;}body{margin:0;}...
</style>
```

I have tried this solution.

```
<style media="all">
  {% include directory ~ '/sites/default/files/css/inline.css' ignore missing %}
</style>
```

But then I only get the response `<style media="all"></style>`

I have tried to add custom CSS as a library and it works fine, but I want the CSS outside the `<css-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token }}">` (if I want to move it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nah, don't do that.

The right way is to create a [sub-theme](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/creating-a-drupal-8-sub-theme-or-sub-theme-of-sub-theme) (with Bartik as base) and add your styles from there: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme

Alternatively you could do that from within a custom module, too: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module

---

If you still insist adding inline CSS, that would be like following:

```
<style>{{ source('sites/default/files/css/inline.css') }}</style>
```

Comment: But does this problem really have someting to do witk Bartik theme?

I would like to write the code if possible, and not have to install another module.

Comment: @Jonathan – Don't override core themes. Your changes will simply get reverted the next time you update Drupal.

Comment: Is there not a easy way to just include a .css file inside a style tag in a twig document?
I have tried to add the files in a library. But i would like to add it outside the "css-placeholder"

Comment: @Jonathan – In web development "easy" means "maintainable". Everything has its place, in every CMS. Create a sub-theme, add your library, done.

Comment: It doesn't have to be maintainable. I just want to ad a single inline css style, included from a css file. Outside the tag <css-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token }}">
I dont need to maintain the css style. It can be "static"

Comment: @Jonathan – If it doesn't need to be maintainable, why then do you insist to do it exactly like that?

Comment: It doesn't really have to be like that. I just need some inline css code within a <style> tag, inside <head> on every page.
But outside the <css-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token }}">

Comment: your solution works perfect! With this i can add inline CSS from external file. Just like I wanted to. Thanks.

Comment: One time it's necessary to use inline CSS is when programmatically rendering a PDF from HTML. You can't just use the site's theme, because the PDF needs to display its content and be downloadable.